# How do I turn off syntax coloring for lines that exceed the word-limit in prelude?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, prelude

I'm using Prelude v 1.0.0. I want to turn off the syntax coloring when my lines exceed a certain word-limit. I don't know where that setting is set. Thanks!

EDIT: I should be more precise. Prelude, by default, sets the color of the text from it's "normal" color to a brighter, more annoying color when it exceeds a certain word-limit. I'm trying to figure out where to tweak it in prelude. I'll give the below suggestion a whirl though.

Comment: Here's some discussion on how to improve font-lock performance: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockSpeed but it doesn't deal with what you want exactly (i.e. it doesn't tell how and whether at all it is possible to not fontify large files).

Comment: Do you mean that Prelude highlights long lines automatically and you want to stop that from happening?

Comment: Does this behavior depend at all on prelude?  It doesn't sound like it, but I don't know much about prelude.

Comment: My guess is that prelude has whitespace-mode turned on by default to highlight long lines.

Comment: @Jordon Biodono is absolutely correct and there are already a few threads on this issue, some of which describe how to turn off whitespace-mode and others about how to customize `whitespace-style`.  One of the other threads even cites the Prelude documentation that discusses this.  I'll list a few of the threads I am aware of that deal with this issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244739/how-to-change-word-wrap-highlighting-in-emacs and https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude#disabling-whitespace-mode and http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Prelude#Turn_off_whitespace_mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@lawlist is correct: This question is a (not-so-obvious) duplicate of [How to change word wrap highlighting in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28244739/1199226) on StackOverflow. Since we can't close questions against posts on other StackExchange sites, I'm going to repeat the answer that I gave over there:

Highlighting of content that exceeds word wrap bounds is provided by `whitespace-mode` (which is actually a built-in mode).

The Prelude [documentation](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/#disabling-whitespace-mode) explains how to disable it:

> **Disabling whitespace-mode**
>
> Although `whitespace-mode` is awesome some people might find it too intrusive. You can disable it in your personal config with the following bit of code:
>
> `(setq prelude-whitespace nil)`

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is already several years old, but for the benefit of people who have this problem and then find this page while searching for a solution:

While looking at some variables (`C-h v whitespace`) that might have been the culprit, I discovered (to make a long story short):

1. `M-x customize-group RET whitespace`
2. Look for the category `Whitespace Style`.
3. Uncheck the box that says, `(Face) Lines, only overlong part`.
4. Finally, reload the major mode of the buffer you're working in (to see the changes right away.)

Since Prelude is good about keeping Customize settings in a separate, dedicated file (`personal/custom.el`), this should be an easy-to-implement, working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the liens of following should work:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^.\\{70,\\}$" 0 default prepend)))
```

I'm not sure if it blocks other keywords from considering same line but I'm sure it's possbile.
Then you'll need to substitute "." with a word regexp, if it's important and adjust the number 70 according to your sepcification.